# Apache Derby: Retrieve column names for an empty table

Tags: java, derby

In JDBC metadata is not set, if the result set is empty, so I cannot execute getColumnNames().

I tried querying the derby systables:

The `SYS.SYSTABLES` table contains `REFERENCEID`, `COLUMNAME`, `COLUMNUMBER`, ...

`COLUMNAME` is what I'm searching for.  But I see no possibility to join this table with SYS.SYSTABLES or any other table.

Comment: Are you SURE the ResultSetMetaData is not set if the result set is empty? I'm pretty sure that ResultSetMetaData is how most tools get the column information, so I'm surprised to hear that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can join systables and syscolumns with `TABLEID = REFERENCEID`

```
select TABLENAME,COLUMNNAME, t.* 
FROM sys.systables t, sys.syscolumns 
WHERE TABLEID = REFERENCEID and tablename = 'SYSCOLUMNS'

 TABLENAME  COLUMNNAME         REFERENCEID                          COLUMNNAME         COLUMNNUMBER COLUMNDATATYPE                                   COLUMNDEFAULT COLUMNDEFAULTID AUTOINCREMENTVALUE AUTOINCREMENTSTART AUTOINCREMENTINC
 ---------- ------------------ ------------------------------------ ------------------ ------------ ------------------------------------------------ ------------- --------------- ------------------ ------------------ ----------------
 SYSCOLUMNS AUTOINCREMENTINC   8000001e-00d0-fd77-3ed8-000a0a0b1900 AUTOINCREMENTINC              9 BIGINT                                           NULL          NULL                          NULL               NULL             NULL
 SYSCOLUMNS AUTOINCREMENTSTART 8000001e-00d0-fd77-3ed8-000a0a0b1900 AUTOINCREMENTSTART            8 BIGINT                                           NULL          NULL                          NULL               NULL             NULL
 SYSCOLUMNS AUTOINCREMENTVALUE 8000001e-00d0-fd77-3ed8-000a0a0b1900 AUTOINCREMENTVALUE            7 BIGINT                                           NULL          NULL                          NULL               NULL             NULL
 SYSCOLUMNS COLUMNDATATYPE     8000001e-00d0-fd77-3ed8-000a0a0b1900 COLUMNDATATYPE                4 org.apache.derby.catalog.TypeDescriptor NOT NULL NULL          NULL                          NULL               NULL             NULL
 SYSCOLUMNS COLUMNDEFAULT      8000001e-00d0-fd77-3ed8-000a0a0b1900 COLUMNDEFAULT                 5 java.io.Serializable                             NULL          NULL                          NULL               NULL             NULL
 SYSCOLUMNS COLUMNDEFAULTID    8000001e-00d0-fd77-3ed8-000a0a0b1900 COLUMNDEFAULTID               6 CHAR(36)                                         NULL          NULL                          NULL               NULL             NULL
 SYSCOLUMNS COLUMNNAME         8000001e-00d0-fd77-3ed8-000a0a0b1900 COLUMNNAME                    2 VARCHAR(128) NOT NULL                            NULL          NULL                          NULL               NULL             NULL
 SYSCOLUMNS COLUMNNUMBER       8000001e-00d0-fd77-3ed8-000a0a0b1900 COLUMNNUMBER                  3 INTEGER NOT NULL                                 NULL          NULL                          NULL               NULL             NULL
 SYSCOLUMNS REFERENCEID        8000001e-00d0-fd77-3ed8-000a0a0b1900 REFERENCEID                   1 CHAR(36) NOT NULL                                NULL          NULL                          NULL               NULL             NULL
```

Answer (score 2):

Use [DatabaseMetaData.getColumns()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/sql/DatabaseMetaData.html#getColumns%28java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String%29)

Answer (score 0):

```
public static String[] retriveColumns(String tablename) throws SQLException
    {
        rs = st.executeQuery("SELECT * FROM " + tablename);
        rsmd = rs.getMetaData();
        int numberOfColumns = rsmd.getColumnCount();
        String names[];
        names = new String[numberOfColumns];
        for(int i=1; i<numberOfColumns; i++)
            {    
             names[i-1] = rsmd.getColumnName(i);
             System.out.println(names[i-1]);
            }
        return names;
   }
```

Comment: While this code snippet may be the solution, [including an explanation](//meta.stackexchange.com/questions/114762/explaining-entirely-‌​code-based-answers) really helps to improve the quality of your post. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, and those people might not know the reasons for your code suggestion

Comment: these libraries are used import 
import java.sql.ResultSet;
import java.sql.SQLException;
import java.sql.Statement;
import java.sql.ResultSetMetaData;
this is a method that accepts a variable string, queries the database for all the columns in the table that matches that string then stores it in a resultset object from that it creates resultsetmetadata object to find out how many columns exist in the table. Then uses a for loop that is initialized at one with the number of columns as the test condition. That was we can pass the loop iteration to getColumnName without overflow.

Comment: Here we debate whether the code is potentially useful but presented in form that must have all the declarations inserted or added to make it work.  Once this is done, it does work but I just can't bring myself to vote it up.  A much better presentation of how it should be presented can be found here: https://www.tutorialspoint.com/java-resultset-getmetadata-method-with-example