# Derby Column names get cut off when using ij

Tags: sql, derby

When I type "Describe [someTable];" the column names for very long columns (over 20 characters) get cut off, and the & symbol is used.  So for example I have two columns that appear to be named WowThisIsAVeryLongC&.

When I run a select * statement the column names are also truncated because the data in them are only 2 or 3 characters long.  I tried using system calls for table and select to export the data to CSV, but those do not give me any header info.  MaximumDisplayWidth only changes the width for the data displayed.  I can not find any way to figure out the correct names of these columns.  This is a database I inherited, so I'm a bit stuck.

Any and all help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Would something like [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/8521248/477878) work?

Comment: That was it.  Thanks Joachim.  For the record, the table was also to huge to copy the text from the terminal.  I just output all table and column names to a file.  Worked great, thanks again.  I'm pasting the modified SQL Query below in hopes it helps someone in the future.

Comment: SYSCS_UTIL.SYSCS_EXPORT_QUERY (
IN 'SELECT TABLENAME,COLUMNNAME, t.* FROM sys.systables t, sys.syscolumns 
WHERE TABLEID = REFERENCEID','/opt/SomeFileName.txt',null,null,null)

Answer (score 1):

If you are using Derby Release 10.10+, then you can use the databaseMetaData  tool.

Here is virtually the same output you would get from the `describe '*'` command:

```
ij> maximumdisplaywidth 1000;
ij> call syscs_util.syscs_register_tool( 'databaseMetaData', true );
Statement executed.
ij> select t.table_schem, t.table_name, c.column_name, c.type_name, c.DECIMAL_DIGITS, c.NUM_PREC_RADIX, c.COLUMN_SIZE, c.COLUMN_DEF, c.CHAR_OCTET_LENGTH, c.IS_NULLABLE 
from table( getTables( null, '%', '%' ) ) t, 
     table( getColumns( null, '%', '%', '%') ) c 
where c.table_schem = t.table_schem 
and c.table_name = t.table_name 
and t.table_type = 'TABLE' 
order by table_schem, table_name, column_name;
```

Other tables and columns attributes for use in SQL clauses can be obtained from the *java.sql.DatabaseMetaData* interface with their corresponding method names and properties (refer the Java API).

(See "Using the databaseMetaData optional tool" in the "Derby Tools and Utilities Guide" for further information).

Answer (score 0):

If just for dumping the output of a select statement, knowing that the data values would be fully displayed up to 128 chars (or more when setting a value with the [MaximumDisplayWidth](https://db.apache.org/derby/docs/10.2/tools/rtoolsijcomref12281.html#rtoolsijcomref12281) command), you can force a column name that is longer than the data values below it to be displayed in full by artificially increasing the size of the data value output in the SELECT query. For instance:

```
ij> select TAG as longColumnNameForShortData, SERIAL as longColumnNameForSerial from ID;
LO&|LONGCOLUMN&
---------------
TM1|23594000
TF1|0
TS1|27188000
```

and then with:

```
ij> select CHAR(TAG,30) as longColumnNameForShortData, CHAR(SERIAL,30) as longColumnNameForSerial from ID;
LONGCOLUMNNAMEFORSHORTDATA    |LONGCOLUMNNAMEFORSERIAL
-------------------------------------------------------------
TM1                           |23594000
TF1                           |0
TS1                           |27190000
```

... a bit stupid but does the job.

Answer (score -1):

Try using the help command in IJ. This should point you to the 
[MaximumDisplayWidth Command](https://builds.apache.org/job/Derby-docs/lastSuccessfulBuild/artifact/trunk/out/tools/rtoolsijcomref12281.html) There is also the [ij.maximumDisplayWidth property](https://builds.apache.org/job/Derby-docs/lastSuccessfulBuild/artifact/trunk/out/tools/rtoolsijpropref28788.html)

Comment: this sets the column width for data but doesn't increase the field for the column name past 10

Comment: defines a maximum, not a minimum, hence no effect on column name truncation above short data values.